# still allowing to buy when out of stock / php, sql

Tags: php

I'm trying to prevent users from buying a product if it is out of stock. The code below is not showing any errors and still allows the user to purchase a product even when stock is below zero. Any suggestions on what I've done wrong?

```
<?php

    $productID= $_GET['ID'];
    $username = $_SESSION['solentuser']; 


    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;","user","pass");

    $results=$conn->query("SELECT stocklevel FROM products");
    $row=$results->fetch();

    if($row['stocklevel'] >= 1){    

        $conn->query("INSERT INTO basket(productID,username,qty) values($productID,'$username',1)");
        $conn->query("UPDATE products SET stocklevel=stocklevel-1 WHERE ID=$productID");
        echo "You have successfully added this product to your basket!";
        echo "<br><br><p> <a href='basket.php'>View my basket!</a></p>";
    }
    else{

        echo "This product is out of stock!";
        echo "<p><a href='index.php'>Back to Search page</a></p>";

    }

    //print_r($conn->errorInfo());
?>
```

Comment: Test seems fine. Are you sure it's not a database problem? Did you really see it drop to 0 in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to change to this : `SELECT stocklevel FROM products WHERE id=$productID`

Because previously you select the stocklevel from all products

Comment: its always these tiny things catching me out!

Answer (score 1):

You have to select product by the product Id

```
<?php

    $productID= $_GET['ID'];
    $username = $_SESSION['solentuser']; 


    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;","user","pass");

    $results=$conn->query("SELECT stocklevel FROM products Where productID=$productID");
    $row=$results->fetch();

    if($row['stocklevel'] >= 1){    

        $conn->query("INSERT INTO basket(productID,username,qty) values($productID,'$username',1)");
        $conn->query("UPDATE products SET stocklevel=stocklevel-1 WHERE ID=$productID");
        echo "You have successfully added this product to your basket!";
        echo "<br><br><p> <a href='basket.php'>View my basket!</a></p>";
    }
    else{

        echo "This product is out of stock!";
        echo "<p><a href='index.php'>Back to Search page</a></p>";

    }

    //print_r($conn->errorInfo());
```

Comment: The idea is right, but change `Where productID` to `Where ID` is more correct

Comment: I know but he is used field name productID so I gave him that.